# Make org agenda full screen

Tags: emacs, org-mode, spacemacs

When I open todo list or agenda, it opens in a mini-buffer (takes up half of my screen). How do I change my dotfile so that when I call `org-agenda` it takes up the entire screen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of Org version 8.3, you can set `org-agenda-window-setup` to
`only-window`.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the other windows after running `org-agenda` by adding `delete-other-windows` to its after advice:  `(advice-add 'org-agenda :after #'delete-other-windows)`.

Comment: Also, I get this error: `apply: Wrong number of arguments: #[(&optional window) "Æ!Ç!ÈÉ\"ÈÃ\"ÊË !ÌÍ-" [window frame function window-side atom-root side-main window-normalize-window window-frame window-parameter delete-other-windows ...] 4 2243840 nil], 2`

Comment: Actually, it still pops up after I remove your code, so it might be a problem on my end

Comment: The # just tells Emacs that the symbol is a function. It's optional.